# Flex div always take remaining height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a web page but I'm having a hard time making it responsive and fit my desires.

I'm making a login page with an alert box, the alert will only appear if the user types a wrong password or email.

What I want to happen is for the main `div` (flex-3) content to be centered on the page and when the alert (flex-2) appears for the page to not have a scroll wheel, so flex-3 kinda has to calculate the remaining height of the page and be centered, and obviously all of this has to work no matter the device resolution.

I tried doing this with flex `div` but the closest I got made so the alert increased the total height of the page, so it would have a scroll wheel with no content at the bottom.

```css
html,
body {
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.flex-1 {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: red;
}

.flex-2 {
    display: flex;
    background-color: green;
}

.flex-3 {
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!-- import bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- import jquery and bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id='navbarNav'>
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="flex-1">
        <div class="flex-2 d-flex alert-test">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I made your solution working.

1. Added `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to `flex-1` to make the 2nd point working.
2. Added `flex-grow: 1` to `flex-3` class to make the dive stretch in remaining area.

Only by adding `display: flex` to the parent class `flex-1`, the flex grow property of child class, `flex-3` works.

Hope this is the solution that you are looking for.

```css
html,
body {
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.flex-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.flex-2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
}

.flex-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- import bootstrap css -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<!-- import jquery and bootstrap -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" />
      </a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div
        class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"
        id="navbarNav"
      >
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="flex-1">
    <div class="flex-2 d-flex alert-test">
      <h1>flex-2 TEST</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <h1>flex-3 Test</h1>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```